# Chrome passwords for equivalent domains

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Is there a way to tell the Chrome password manager that websites https://a.b.c and https://d.e.f are in fact equivalent and use the same login credentials, so that when I change my password in website 1 it will also know that my new password also applies to website 2?

UPDATE: I asked this question last year. Recently, Google created their new Password Manager which allows you to type a list of domains for each saved password. Therefore this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is no longer relevant to the current version.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible,

1. To declare that the website, for  https://a.b.c,can share credentials with https://d.e.f, create a file named assetlinks.json with the following content:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://a.b.c"
  }
 },
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://d.e.f"
  }
 }]
```

For sites to share sign-in credentials, specify the string delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds

2. Host the Digital Asset Links JSON file at the following location on the sign-in domain: `https://domain[:optional_port]/.well-known/assetlinks.json` e.g `https://a.b.c/.well-known/assetlinks.json` and `https://d.e.f/.well-known/assetlinks.json` if singin/singup form located on both websites

[official google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/site-affiliation/#:%7E:text=%23-,Associate%20your%20two%20websites,-To%20declare%20that)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works for website owners. I was interested if there was a solution for myself as a browser user.